# Why HCL does not damage the walls of our stomach?

Tags: digestion, stomach

As we know that HCL is strong acid. It is very dangerous and corrosive to skin and can damage the skin tissues very badly and if it is drunk by someone then his health is strongly affected and he may died. But when HCL produced  by our stomach it does not harms the wall of our stomach.

**Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stomach is protected by two enzymes, COX 1 and COX 2 (Cyclooxygenase 1 and 2). These are prostaglandin enzymes. From [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11595412) article on NIH:

> ...both COX-1 and COX-2 either alone or in concert contribute to gastric mucosal defence

This is why long term use of COX non-specific NSAIDs can cause severe stomach problems, since they inhibit the production or function of these enzymes. There may be other processes that further protect the stomach from the effects of hydrochloric acid, but I believe these enzymes play the most important roles, especially when one considers the effect caused by inhibiting their function.

Comment: If only you could combine you're answer with @unetempest

Comment: @CareyGregory, I would but a) I would be copying someone else's answer, and b) as far as I can tell goblet cells are found in the small and large intestines where they protect them from acids produced by the stomach but are not actually found in the stomach: https://www.bioexplorer.net/goblet-cells.html/

Comment: The cells in the stomach responsible for its protection are foveolar cells. The COX enzymes are active in giving those cells their acid protecting characteristics.